# Managing local Maven dependency versions when the dependency of one module is also a module in the same IntelliJ project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependency-management

I think this question is best asked with an example.

I have an IntelliJ project open, `Alice`.

Inside `Alice`, I have two modules, `Bob` and `Cat`. Both `Bob` and `Cat` are Maven projects.

So the folder structure looks like this:

```
Alice
- Bob
- Cat
```

Say `Bob` depends on `Cat`.

The relevant parts of their pom files may look like this:

For `Bob`:

```
<groupId>some.group</groupId>
<artifactId>bob</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>cat</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

For `Cat`:

```
<groupId>some.group</groupId>
<artifactId>cat</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
```

Now, I need to make an update to `Bob`.

Say that in `Cat` there is a class `CatUtils`.

I add a brand new method to `CatUtils`, `CatUtils.foo()`. This is a minor API change so I update `Cat` to version `1.0.1`.

Now I'm working on `Bob`. In `Bob`, I use `CatUtils.foo()`.

IntelliJ doesn't mark it as problematic in any way. The thing is, there is a problem. The problem is `Cat:1.0.0`, which is what `Bob` depends on according to its `pom.xml` file, *does not contain `CatUtils.foo()`*.

But, because IntelliJ sees the full source of both files, it looks and says "yep, `CatUtils` has a `foo()` method, you're all good".

But when you actually package `Bob`, it will rely on `Cat:1.0.0` instead of `Cat:1.0.1`, because you haven't updated `pom.xml` for `Bob` to use `Cat:1.0.1` yet. Since `Cat:1.0.0` doesn't have `CatUtils.foo()`, the `mvn package` fails.

So the question, is there a way for IntelliJ to autocomplete / error-check against the version of a dependency actually built in the repo, instead of the local source code of that dependency? `mvn package` seems like a pretty late time to find this kind of error - I want to see as I'm writing the code that I'm relying on API changes that aren't present in the version currently depended on.

Comment: I have always used `${project.version}` and defined `dependencyManagement` in the parent POM. This is apparently technically not supposed to work, and IDEs might complain about it, but I've never had any problem in practice.

Comment: @rococo Are the projects fully dependant? And are they just share the folder structure or Alice is actually a Maven parent to the other two projects?

Comment: Did you re-import project in Maven tool window after the version change? What result do you get when build by Maven in command line?

Comment: Where does IDE navigate you when you Ctrl(Cmd)click on the old dependency in pom?